# Different height issue with same font-size & line height in each browser - Safari, Chrome, FF? How to have all of them pixel perfect & same height?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, browser

Different height issue  with same font-size & line height in each browser - Safari, Chrome, FF? How to have all of them pixel perfect & same height?

I have this simple code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        span {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            line-height: 1;
            font-size: 11pt;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: fit-content;
            height: fit-content;
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <span onclick="document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = getComputedStyle(this).height">CLICK ME!</span>
    <span id="output"></span>
</body>

</html>
```

This gives me different heights in each browser:

```
Chrome: 14px

Safari: 15px

Firefox: 14.6667px
```

**I have tried switching from `span` to `div` but the issue persists. I already have `line-height:1` and `padding`, `margin` set to 0 too.**

This height difference might not seem like much in this simple example but my actual use case has much larger height differences as I have lots of spans and divs and I need all of them to fit in a fixed sized container. I am designing a resume builder in browser and require all the content to fit in a fixed size container. This difference in heights causes things to overflow in Safari and a bit in Firefox. In each case, Chrome seems to squeeze things the most.

I can't use fixed height because my actual content will have multi-lined content.

You can test this JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/5s40jhyf/3/

Comment: Why use `pt`? Is this for printing? + you are logging the computed style, not necessarily the rendered one, use getBoundingClientRect().height for this, but this will most likely still vary across browsers.

Comment: @Kaiido Using `pt` because my actual use case is a resume builder and it required me to use `11pt` standard for resume.

Comment: o_O `pt` on a digital display is meaningless. If it's not for printing, use an unit made for digital displays like `px`. If for printing, not sure the cross-browser issue will stand once going to the printer.

Comment: @Kaiido I also noticed that if I use `14px` then it prints the same height in all browsers. However if I use `14.5px`, then it prints `15px` in Safari and `14px` in Chrome and Firefox. For resume, `14.5px` looks the closest to `11pt` but Safari doesn't seem to like the decimal size.

Comment: *How to have all of them pixel perfect & same height?* --> use the same font-family, don't rely on the default browser one, sans-serif can be a different font for each browser

Comment: Yes Chrome and Safari will round the computed values, but once again these are just the computed values, not the actual size of your element. Use getBoundingClientRect() to get the actual size of your element (as a float in every browsers)

Comment: @TemaniAfif my original example was actually using a different font-family `Poppins` before I updated the question to remove it as this issue persists with Poppins too. You can check the Poppins example here: https://jsfiddle.net/5s40jhyf/2/

Comment: @Kaiido The issue persists with `getBoundingClientRect()` too. Firefox gives an even longer `14.666671752929688`, Chrome gives `14` and Safari gives `15` https://jsfiddle.net/6pufqz0d/